# How does physical sample size impact the estimate and error on abundance in a larger volume?

Tags: experiment-design

Suppose I have a fixed volume containing particles (or bacteria, or Cladocera). I want to infer the total amount of particles in the volume based on taking a (or more) small liquid sample.

By stirring before taking the sample, I can assume that the particles are homogeneously distributed in the volume.

1. How does the sample size (ratio to total volume) impact the estimate for the total abundance and an estimate for the error on the total abundance?
2. How to take into account errors (measurement error on the sample volume, I assume the particle count is correct) in the density measurement of the sample(s).

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be the total volume and $\lambda$ the mean number of particles per volume unit, that is, the particle number density. Let $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ be the results of $n$ independent particle counts. Under the homogeneity assumption, we can at least hope that this constitutes a sample from a Poisson distribution, and using that to do the estimation.

But there are some problems: If $n=1$, the sample will give no indication if the Poisson assumption is untenable. For instance, even with some sort of "global" homogeneity, the assumptions of a Poisson process could not be met. The density could be to high, or there cold be some chemical/physical processes causing attraction or repulsion. So, to be able to detect that, use $n$ sufficiently large. An alternative to Poisson could then be a negative binomial distribution, or you could estimate via quasi-Poisson regression.

For the second point, first do a separate experiment to estimate the error in measurement of volume.